# CMake suppress project's languages support (linking with 3rd party lib)

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to link my `CMake`-project with `pcre` lib wich is already is shipped with a `CMakeLists.txt`, so it promises to be easily. However, I'd like to build it only for C language, no C++.

My question is whether it possible to override the list of supported languages?

`pcre`'s `CMakeLists.txt` has the following `project` command:

```
PROJECT(PCRE C CXX)
```

So it builds, by default, `CXX` targets as well. I do not need them as my whole project is written in the "plain old C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is following line in pcre's CMakeLists.txt:

```
OPTION(PCRE_BUILD_PCRECPP "Build the PCRE C++ library (pcrecpp)." ON)
```

I suppose, you should set this var to `OFF`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that option. I figured out that it could be set up by `-D` command line options of `cmake`. But instead of `OFF` I use `NO` and it works. Anyway, I'm curious how to (if it is possible at all) suppress `project`'s settings on what languages it supports.

Comment: You can use `0`, `NO` and `OFF` value for BOOL type. As for `project`, why do you care about it? It's purpose is to set up some internal CMake stuff, it shouldn't affect you in any way.